# webgoat can not startup with tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, owasp

**The web app has a jar here [/Users/joey/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/webapps/webgoat/WEB-INF/lib/webgoat-classloader-6.1.0.jar] ,which includes a class [public class PluginClassLoader extends WebappClassLoader].
I think it is the classloader configue problem ,but please help me.**
08-Jul-2015 00:56:04.648 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal LifecycleException 
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.webgoat.classloader.PluginClassLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when running with...

> mvn tomcat:run-war

But it didn't occur when running via

> java -jar target/webgoat-container-6.1.0-war-exec.jar

That worked, so I stopped trying to figure out what went wrong with mvn.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Tomcat 8, but I actually resolved my very similar error and got Webgoat to build with Maven and Tomcat 7.

Webgoat's documentation is not very centralized across versions, so I was confused for a bit, but I found

```
mvn clean tomcat7:run-war
```

at this link https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat-Legacy/wiki/Installation-(WebGoat-6.0) under the Source Distribution section.

I imagine it might be worth trying with ***tomcat8*** instead just for giggles.

Hope it helps.